# NullPointer Exception on setAdapter() when tapping Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

> I'm creating a kind of corporate app which introduces member of the company.
>
> I would like to change an intent when tapping the list of navigation drawer.
>
> When tapping the navigation drawer(R.id.member), I get NullPointer Exception on setAdapter(),but I don't know how to fix it.
>
> Please help.

Main

```
  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_corporate) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_member) {
        Intent member_intent = new Intent();
        member_intent.setClassName("com.example.navigationdrawer", "com.example.navigationdrawer.Member");
        startActivity(member_intent);


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_history) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_business) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
 }
}
```

error log

```
Process: com.example.navigationdrawer, PID: 740
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.navigationdrawer/com.example.navigationdrawer.Member}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.example.navigationdrawer.Member.onCreate(Member.java:51)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

listview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Member.java (the changed intent when tapping the list of nav-drawer)

```
public class Member extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayList<MemberProfile> memberProfilesList;

    memberProfilesList = new ArrayList<>();
    memberProfilesList.add(new MemberProfile("Kate","CEO",R.drawable.human,"I'm CEO。"));
    memberProfilesList.add(new MemberProfile("Ben","PR Manager", R.drawable.human1,"Love sweets"));
    memberProfilesList.add(new MemberProfile("Alex","SNS Manager", R.drawable.human2,"My job is PR and SNS manager."));



    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, memberProfilesList);


    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            MemberProfile memberProfile = (MemberProfile)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent sub = new Intent();
            sub.putExtra("list_names", memberProfile.getName());
            sub.putExtra("list_jobs",memberProfile.getJob());
            sub.putExtra("list_images",memberProfile.getImage());
            sub.putExtra("list_comments",memberProfile.getComment());


            sub.setClassName("com.example.navigationdrawer", "com.example.navigationdrawer.SubActivity");
            startActivity(sub);

        }
    });



}
```

}

[debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDXmr.jpg)

**breaking on listView.setAdapter debug error**

```
Process: com.example.navigationdrawer, PID: 27652
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
                                                                              at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                              at com.example.navigationdrawer.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:24)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5786)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

SubActivity

```
public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sub_activity);



    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Intent sub = getIntent();

    String name = sub.getStringExtra("list_names");
    String job = sub.getStringExtra("list_jobs");
    int image = sub.getIntExtra("list_images", R.drawable.human);
    String comment = sub.getStringExtra("list_comments");


    text.setText(name);
    text2.setText(job);
    imageView.setImageResource(image);
    text3.setText(comment);



}
```

}

> text.setText(name);
>
> text2.setText(job);
>
> imageView.setImageResource(image);
>
> text3.setText(comment);

these shows NPE warning(yellow highlight) on android studio

Comment: Post your Log file

Comment: Are you sure that listView is in _content_main.xml_ file?

Comment: listView is in the listviews.xml.I want to show content_main.xml layout at first and when tapping the list, show listviews.xml layout

Comment: then you should _listviews.xml_ file

Comment: edited it but nothing changes.